# Ideals $\neq0$ in $F[x]$ & Euclidean domains are generated by elements $\neq0$ of minimal degree (Euclidean size), so Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, minimal-polynomials

Consider the following

> *Theorem* Let $F$ be a field, $I$ a nonzero ideal in $F[x]$, and $g(x)$ an element of $F[x]$. Then, $I= \langle g(x)\rangle$ if and only if $g(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial of minimum degree in $I$.

Now it gets completely foggy what is meant by "minimum degree". I constantly come across the "minimal polynomial". This seems to be linked, but it seems strange that there is a division here.

Could someone give a pointer to what the second line actually means. Maybe some example or diagram (if possible) would help a lot here.

Comment: "minimum degree" means smallest occurring degree among the nonzero elements of $I$. Kind of like the richest non-queen person in the United Kingdom. It does not have a direct relation to "minimum polynomial" (although the latter is a nonzero polynomial of nonzero degree in a certain ideal, but not all ideals have to arise in that context).

Comment: How is what you are citing a **definition**? I can see no term in that sentence at all whose meaning is being explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $I=\{p(x) \in \Bbb{R}[x] \, | \, p(0)=0 \}$. It is easy to see that this is an ideal of $\Bbb{R}[x]$. For example, $x^2+x, x^{100}-7x$, they are all members of $I$. But is there a non-zero polynomial with smallest degree that lives in here?

If you think a bit more you will see that $x \in I$ is **an example** of a non-zero polynomial of least degree that lives in $I$. Furthermore every member of $I$ can be represented as $xk(x)$ for some $k(x) \in \Bbb{R}[x]$. Thus one can reason that  $I=\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: quibble:  $x$ is the *monic* non-zero polynomial of least degree in $I$; $ax$ with $a\in\Bbb R-\{0,1\}$ are other non-zero polynomials of least degree in $I$

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, when they say "$g(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial of minimum degree in $I$" they simply mean that of all of the polynomials in $I$, $g(x)$ has the smallest degree. Recall that for polynomials in one variable that the degree is the maximal power of $x$ appearing in $g(x)$ that has a nonzero coefficient. In other words, if $f(x) = f_nx^n+f_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+f_1x+f_0$ and $f_n\neq 0$ then the degree of $f(x)$ is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem** $ $ An ideal $I\neq 0\,$ in a Euclidean domain (i.e. having division with *smaller* remainder) is generated by any element $\,0\neq \color{0a0}{g\in I}\,$ with min Euclidean size (= least polynomial degree in OP).

**Proof** $\ $ The [key idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) is  *ideals are closed under remainder (mod)*, so a *minimal* size $\,\color{#0a0}{g\in I}\,$ must $
\rm\color{#c00}{divide}$ every $\,f\in I\,$ (else the remainder $\,0\neq f\bmod g = f-q\,g\in I\,$ and is *smaller* size than $\,g,\,$ contra minimality of $\,g).\,$ Thus $\,\color{#c00}{(g)\supseteq I}\color{#0a0}{\supseteq (g)}\,$ so $\,I = (g).\ \ \small\bf QED$

The descent in this proof can be interpreted *constructively* as computing a generator of $\,I\,$ by computing the gcd of its elements (by taking repeated remainders as in the Euclidean algorithm). Thus "minimal" is with respect to the *size measure* used for remainders in (Euclidean) division with *smaller* remainder.

**Remark** $ $ The minimal polynomial of an element $\:\!\alpha\:\!$ algebraic over a field $F$  is indeed a special case, since it is the (monic) minimal degree element of the ideal of polynomials $\,f\in F[x]\,$ with $\,f(\alpha) = 0$. As above, it can be viewed as the gcd of all such polynomials having $\alpha$ as a root, and the gcd yields $\rm\color{#c00}{descent\!:}$ $\,f_1(\alpha)=0=f_2(\alpha)\,\Rightarrow\, g(\alpha) = 0,\,$ $\ g := \gcd(f_1,f_2) = af+bg,\,$ and the gcd will have $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ degree than $f_1,f_2\,$  if they  are incomparable (i.e. if neither divides the other). If we disassemble the gcds into assembly language = iterated remainders (mods) then this is the same descent by remainder that is used in the above proof that $I$ is principal.

**Generalization** the  idea extends to PIDs: [(Dedekind-Hasse criterion)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242)
a domain $\,D\,$ is a PID iff for  $\:0\neq a, b \in D,\:$
either $\:a\:|\:b\:$ or some $D$-linear combination $\:ad+bc\:$ is "smaller" than $\,a.\,$ In a PID we can choose  as a "size" measure the number of prime factors (counting multiplicity).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3511688/242).