# Proof that every element of a Euclidean domain has a $\gcd$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, euclidean-domain

I am required to prove that every element $a$ and $b$ of a Euclidean domain $E$ has a greatest common divisor.
Here's my approach.
Let $D=\{ax + by: a,b,x,y \in E \} $
We claim that $D$ is an ideal of $E$

For it is clear that $D$ is closed under addition and subtraction and that if $c_1,c_2 \in D$ then so is $c_1c_2 \land c_2c_1$
Also, for every $r \in E$ and $c \in D$ then $cr, rc \in D$ as
$cr = (ax + by)r =a(xr)+ b(yr) \in D$
Similar arguments also holds for $rc$.
Now we have established that $D$ is an Ideal of $E$.
Now since every ideal of a Euclidean domain is a Principal Ideal Domain
It follows that $D$ has a generator,say

$D = <d>$
Now, $a \in D$ as for $x=1, y=0 \in D$
$ax + by \in E \implies a\cdot1 + b\cdot0 = a \in D$
And similarly,
$a\cdot0 + b\cdot1 = b \in E$
Hence $a \in D, b \in D$
And since $D$ is generated by $<d>$
There are elements $q_1,q_2 \in E$ such that
$d = aq_1 \land d= bq_2$
Which implies that $a|d \land b|d$
Now let $c$ be an arbitrary divisor of $a$ and $b$
Then by definition, $c=ax \land c= by$
Also $c$ must divide any linear combination of $a$ and $b$, thus,in particular
$c|(ax + by) \implies c|d$
Hence we have proved that $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a,b$. This completes the proof.

I gathered the ideas for this proof from resources I found on the web. I would like to know if my approach is sound.
I wish to present this proof in an exam, the one given to us during the class depends on the constructive proof of the Euclidean algorithm which I found messy and unattractive.
If this approach is not sound someone should please show me a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean that every *pair* of elements has a gcd?

Comment: Yes. Every pair of element in a Euclidean domain.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289264/242) the linked dupe for the standard proof by Euclidean remainder descent. For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.

Answer (score -1):

- Edit to correct your title as suggested by J. W. Tanner, instead of answering his comment.
- $D\ne\{ax + by: a,b,x,y \in E \}$ ($a,b$ are fixed) $D=\{ax + by: x,y \in E \}.$
- "if $c_1,c_2 \in D$ then so are $c_1c_2$ and $c_2c_1$" is (weaker hence) redundant with "for every $r \in E$ and $c \in D$ then $cr, rc \in D$".
- "Similar arguments also holds for $rc$" does not work. You have to assume $E$ commutative.
- "Which implies that $a|d \land b|d$" no: $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b.$
- "$c=ax \land c= by$" no: $a=cx$ and $b=cy$ (anyway useless).
- "in particular $c|(ax + by) \implies c|d$" explain more (who are your $x,y$? not the useless previous ones).

Comment: x and y are in E.

Comment: Of course, but justify your implication by an appropriate choice of them.

Comment: Alright.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: ? All of a sudden, a strange downvote 9 days later...