# A question on a presumably erroneous proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I'm working through an exercise in an algebra book that asks one to prove that given the field $F$, considering the ring of polynomials over $F$ given by $F[x]$, that if $f$ is a degree 1 polynomial, then $(f)$, the principal ideal generated by $f$, is maximal.

I understand this is special case of the fact that the ideals generated by irreducible elements are maximal. I've attempted to prove this and came to something that looks like a solution, but it appears I am either somewhere implicitly using that $\text{deg} f = 1$, or otherwise unable to see my error.

**My proof:**
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $(f)$ is not maximal, i.e. there is some ideal $I$ such that:
$$(f) \subsetneq I \subsetneq R$$
Obviously then, $I \setminus (f)$ is nonempty then. By the well-ordering principle, we can consider then a polynomial of minimal degree in $I \setminus (f)$. \ \
By definition, $f \nmid g$, as this would have $g \in (f)$. Appealing to the division algorithm for polynomials then, we have a unique decomposition of $g$ given by the following:
\begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            g = fq + r \\
            q, r \in F[x], \; \text{deg}(r) < \text{deg}(g)
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
As $f \nmid g$ then, it must be $r \neq 0$. Reorganizing, we get
$$r = g - fq,$$
where $r \in I$ as $g \in I$ and $-fq = f(-q) \in (f) \subsetneq I$, appealing to fact that $I$ as an ideal is additive subgroup.
There are two possibilities then, that $r \in (f)$ or $r \in I \setminus (f)$. If $r \in (f)$, then using the first line in (1) and the properties of ideals, it is clear then that we must have $g \in (f)$, a contradiction.
If $r \in I \setminus (f)$ instead, then as $\text{deg}(r) < \text{deg}(g)$, the minimality of the degree of $g$ is contradicted. Thus both cases yield a contradiction, and so it must be $(f)$ is maximal.

Any help in ascertaining the error or providing insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't conclude that $\text{det}(r)<\text{deg}(g)$, because $\text{deg}(r)=\text{deg}(g)$ if (and only if) $q=0$. 

So your proof gets you to the point where you can conclude that $q=0$ (ie $r=g$, and $g$ already had degree less than the degree of $f$). Next is where you use $\text{deg}(f)=1$.

Answer (score -1):

You are essentially *inlining* the ubiquitous [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289264/242) that ideals in a Euclidean domain are principal, generated by any minimal element. This implies $\,I = (g)\,$ so $\,(g)\supsetneq (f)\,\Rightarrow\, g\mid f\,$ *properly*, hence $f$ irreducible $\Rightarrow \,g\,$ is a unit, so $I=(g)=(1)$.

**Note** $ $ Viewed *constructively* the descent step yields [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3130465/242) for computing inverses mod primes: if prime $\,p\nmid a\,$ then we can invert $\,a\,$ modulo $\,p\,$ by using the descent $\,a \to p\bmod a\,$ to get a decreasing chain of multiples of $a$, eventually terminating with $1$, so $(p,a)=(1).\,$

In the OP special case where $f$ has degree $1$ we can instead use the general fact that in a Euclidean domain if $p\neq 0$ is a nonunit of minimal Euclidean size (here degree) then remainders mod $p\,$ are units $\,u\,$ (or $\,0),\,$ so if $\,p\nmid a\, $ then $\,a = q\,p + u\,$ so unit $\,u = a-q\,p\in (a,p)\Rightarrow (a,p)=(1),\,$ thus $(p)$ is max (said structurally: $(p)$ is max by $R/p\,$ is a field, by mod $p\,$ nonzero elements are units).

Applied in $F[x]\!:\:\!$ the minimal degree nonunits $\,p\,$ are precisely the polynomials of degree $1,\,$ so by above $(p)$ is max (so $p$ is prime).  Applied in $\Bbb Z$ this merely proves that $\color{#c00}{2,3}$ are prime, but applied in quadratic number rings it can be much more useful, e.g. allowing us easily to deduce that certain quadratic number rings are not Euclidean. [For example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23844/the-ring-bbb-z-left-frac-1-sqrt-192-right-is-not-a-euclidean-domai?rq=1#comment9869579_23872) if $\pm1$ are the only units of an integral domain $R$ then $R$ is not Euclidean if $\,a^3−a\,$ is coprime to $\,b^3-b\,$ for some $\,a,b\,$ in $R\,$ or, said equivalently, if neither $\,\Bbb Z/\color{#c00}2\,$ nor $\,\Bbb Z/\color{#c00}3\,$ is an image of $R,\,$ i.e. $R$ has neither *parity* nor *triality* (which yields a [slick proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23872/242) by Lenstra that the PID $\,\Bbb Z[1 + \sqrt{-19})/2]\,$ is not Euclidean).